# How to fix 'No such file or directory' warning when building with Applovin SDK and Google Admob Mediation

Tags: xcode, admob, applovin

I keep getting this warning message when I was building my App with GoogleMobileAdsMediationAppLovin. It seems its trying to find an Applovin precompiled header file from '/Users/thomasso/'. However, I have no idea where does 'thomasso' come from.

I am currently running with Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.43.1), GoogleMobileAdsMediationAppLovin (6.3.0.0) and AppLovinSDK (6.3.0).
I have checked my 'Apple Clang - Language' Precompile Prefix Header row and it's set to No

```
warning: /Users/thomasso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppLovin-bwbdusdjdlnonrfwpebkwzrtnsop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/sdk-Prefix-bolhsipvvnlaapgcaksiouwnzzai/sdk-Prefix.pch.pch: No such file or directory
note: while processing /Users/thomasso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppLovin-bwbdusdjdlnonrfwpebkwzrtnsop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/sdk-Prefix-bolhsipvvnlaapgcaksiouwnzzai/sdk-Prefix.pch.pch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the warning is fixed with AppLovin's iOS SDK 6.6.0. You will have to wait until AdMob certifies against that version to have the warning removed.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this issue was resolved after the latest update!